# Why jenkins could not install git plugin in docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am install jenkins lastest version in docker(Docker version 1.13.1, build 07f3374/1.13.1) using this command:

```
docker run --name="jenkins" -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /home/dolphin/app/third-party/jenkins:/home/dolphin/app/third-party/jenkins/jenkins_home jenkins
```

The output shows install the lastest version of jenkins.But I could not install the git plugin and many other plugin,shows:

```
Warning: This plugin requires dependent plugins that require Jenkins 2.73.3 or newer. Jenkins will refuse to load the dependent plugins requiring a newer version of Jenkins, and in turn loading this plugin will fail.
```

The current jenkins version is:2.60.3.

How to fix it? how to get the right version?

PS: the os version-> CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

Comment: `latest` on the Jenkins DockerHub isn't always latest from my experience. I'd recommend pulling the specific tag of the version you want.

Comment: docker pull jenkins:2.73.3,tips:manifest for docker.io/jenkins:2.73.3 not found@Dandy

Comment: Honestly, the age of that version alone, if you're starting from scratch might as well use the most recent build: `2.164.1` alternatively, `2.73.1` appears to be the closest to the version you've referenced.

Comment: docker pull jenkins:2.164.1
Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/jenkins ... 
manifest for docker.io/jenkins:2.164.1 not found@Dandy

Comment: See my answer: `docker pull jenkins/jenkins:2.164.1` - You should use this

Comment: fix my problem perfectly,thank you@Dandy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to DockerHub Jenkins repository, latest was updated 3 hours ago:

https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/tags

So I'd expect this to use the latest build, maybe you've pulled down incorrectly?

Either way, the closest available version to yours is here `2.73.1`:

https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/tags?page=15

You should pull down using this:

`docker pull jenkins/jenkins:latest`